# Do I can work with Gart Toolkit in Visual Studio 2013 for WP8 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, geolocation, visual-studio-2013, augmented-reality

I have watched other opininions about Gart Toolkit in Windows Phone 7.5, but I have some errors. When I work with this toolkit, it shows an exception, I don't know that spend.

Comment: What is the exception?  That will help track down the issue.

Comment: Already, I resolved this, I was using the GART.dll of x86, now I changed for ARM version. ^_^